# How are consonants combined with an "h" and double consonants borrowed from English?

Tags: letras

Most cognates of English words spelled with consonants combined with an "h" or double letters are spelled with single letters in Spanish. In Spanish "ll" is pronounced as a digraph with the "y" sound. However, very few words in Spanish with "ll" actually correspond to English words spelt with "ll", for example, "millón", "valle", "villano/villana", "brillante". "ch" and "rr" also exist in Spanish, but again there are very few words in Spanish actually correspond to English words spelt with "ch" and "rr". So, I just cannot understand why the Spanish language rarely uses consonants combined with an "h" or double letters.

Comment: If you want to emphasize a specific subquestion, it's best to edit that into the question itself and not leave them in comments. See the [Help Center](/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Your attempt to compare Spanish and English here does not work. And yes, el valle **can be** valley sometimes. You cannot compare languages until you actually know them. They have to be studied separately and only then can you look at their evolution.

Comment: Users here answer questions strictly **voluntarily**. Please do not use flags, suggested edits and multiple comments to push a user to answer a question. If commenting once and/or offering a bounty does not work, please leave it be. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spanish does not have double consonants in spelling, except the digraphs *rr* and *ll*. The only other combination of written consonants with a particular sound is *ch*.

In English, most double consonants are not pronounced any differently from the single consonants (their only effect is to show that the previous vowel is short). So in Spanish, when dealing with English double consonants, it makes sense to simplify the spelling.

Since Spanish does have *rr* and the sound of *rr* is a bit like the English *r*, an English word with *rr* is usually adopted in Spanish without changing that spelling.

Spanish and English *ch* are virtually identical so that doesn't change either.

Spanish doesn't formally have *sh*, but the sound is simple enough and well-known that an English word with *sh* usually keeps this digraph.

The sound of English *th* is found in some varieties of Spanish, but most borrowings are made via the written word, not by actually hearing the words, so Spanish tends to change *th* to *t*. (Most Spanish speakers don't know that English *th* is pronounced as it is, or if they do, they find it natural to approximate it to the sound of Spanish *t*).

English also has *gh*, which in itself has several wildly different pronunciations. I'm not aware of borrowings which originally had a *gh*, but in any case, in Spanish it feels natural to reduce it to *g* because Spanish *h* is silent.

Comment: *Millón* is not a borrowing from English.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question. Outside of borrowings, Spanish has fairly simple orthographical rules, which (except for *rr* and *ll*) don't allow for double consonants unless the sound is really double. If you have a doubt about a particular word or a particular rule, you should ask a question specific to that.

Comment: I think the key point is that we do not usually have double consonants in English. The only ones I can think of are in compound words like bookcase, non-negotiable, half-formed, .... The written language is deceptive, anyone who desires to understand English spelling is in for a lot of heartache.

Comment: The word is originally Italian, *milione*. It was borrowed by Spanish and by Old French separately, and then by English from Old French.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the examples in this answer are taken from [1].

Loan words are initially written as in their original language, and then gradually change to the Spanish spelling rules, while trying to keep a similar pronunciation. In Spanish, there are no double consonants except "rr" and "ll".

In the case of **ch**, there are indeed anglicisms in Spanish that use "ch", such as "chat", "chip", or "cheto" (from *cheat*). There is no other way to write this sound in Spanish, so the "ch" is usually kept.

In the case of **rr**, the sound denoted by "rr" in Spanish does not exist in English, but there are still some loan words that use "rr", usually because they keep it from the English version. For example, *array* (in programming), or the famous and seldom used "cederrón", meaning *CD-ROM*.

In the case of *ll*, this sound is usually written as "y" in English. As the Spanish "y" has a very similar sound, there is no reason to switch from "y" to "ll", so loan words **from English** usually keep it as "y". For example, *yard* -> "yarda". When transforming a word that is written with "j" or "ge", "gi" in English, it also seems that the Spanish spelling "y" is preferred, such as in *jump* -> "yompear" (this seems to be a quite localized word). This might be because the "j" sound in English is closer to the "y" sound than to the "ll" sound in the Spanish dialects that distinguish these two sounds.

However, loans from other languages that use "ll" with the "y" sound do keep the "ll" in the Spanish spelling. For example, the French word *gaillard* becomes "gallardo".

<sub>[1] Moreno-Fernández, Francisco. "Diccionario de anglicismos del español estadounidense." Informes del Observatorio/Observatorio Reports (2018): 037-01. Available online: https://www.nhh.no/contentassets/0eec8ce1f2bf4fe2b48d8fd68277fc44/diccionario_anglicismos.pdf</sub>

Comment: "words initially written as in their original language, and then gradually change to the Spanish spelling rules, while trying to keep a similar pronunciation." Well, there are also words that are written as in their original language, and then gradually change to the Spanish pronunciation rules, while trying to keep a similar spelling. For example "jungle" is translated as "jungla" even though Spanish pronounces the "j" as "h". So I am asking for examples of words spelled with the same letters in both Spanish and English. The link you used is not a reliable source.

Comment: You seem to want a general rule for the spelling of borrowed words. There is none. Each word is borrowed in particular circumstances and gets adapted to Spanish (in pronunciation and spelling) in its own particular way.

Comment: I do not understand why serious users here do not comment on the invalidity of some of these questions asked by this OP. But let's just for a second see one example of all this: "jungle is translated as jungla". Translations are one thing, word origins in different languages are another. This is all apples and oranges, and this is not the first question like this. [By the way, wimi, I understand neither your comment nor the first one under the question.]